# rails5でRspec実行時にFailure/Errorエラーが出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

参考書「rails5速習演習ガイド」に沿ってtaskleafというタスク管理アプリケーションを作成しているのですが、Rspec実行時にFailure/Errorエラーが出て解決法がわからないので質問させてください。

ルートディレクトリの Users/user/rails/taskleaf にて
`$ bundle exec rspec spec/system/tasks_spec.rb` を実行後、以下のようなエラー文が出ます。

補足
`('../config/environment', __dir__)` が書かれているfileは spec/rails_helper.rb です。

よろしくお願いします。

**環境**
Rails 5.2.4
Ruby 2.6.3

---

↓以下エラー全文です。

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)


NameError:
  uninitialized constant BetterErrors
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
# ./config/initializers/better_errors.rb:1:in `<main>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:663:in `block in load_config_initializer'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:662:in `load_config_initializer'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# NameError:
#   uninitialized constant BetterErrors
#   ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00005 seconds (files took 4.78 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

---

tasks_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'タスク管理機能', type: :system do
  let(:user_a) { FactoryBot.create(:user, name: 'ユーザーA', email: 'a@example.com') }
  let(:user_b) { FactoryBot.create(:user, name: 'ユーザーB', email: 'b@example.com') }
  let!(:task_a) { FactoryBot.create(:task, name: '最初のタスク', user: user_a) }

  before do
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'メールアドレス', with: login_user.email
    fill_in 'パスワード', with: login_user.password
    click_button 'ログインする'
  end

  shared_examples_for 'ユーザーAが作成したタスクが表示される' do
    it { expect(page).to have_content '最初のタスク' }
  end

  describe '一覧表示機能' do
    context 'ユーザーAがログインしているとき' do
      let(:login_user) { user_a }

      it_behaves_like 'ユーザーAが作成したタスクが表示される'
    end

    context 'ユーザーBがログインしているとき' do
      let(:login_user) { user_b }

      it 'ユーザーAが作成したタスクが表示されない' do
        expect(page).to have_no_content '最初のタスク'
      end
    end
  end

  describe '詳細表示機能' do
    context 'ユーザーAがログインしているとき' do
      let(:login_user) { user_a }

      before do
        visit task_path(task_a)
      end

      it_behaves_like 'ユーザーAが作成したタスクが表示される'
    end
  end

  describe '新規作成機能' do
    let(:login_user) { user_a }
    let(:task_name) { '新規作成のテストを書く' } # デフォルトとして設定

    before do
      visit new_task_path
      fill_in '名称', with: task_name
      click_button '登録する'
    end

    context '新規作成画面で名称を入力したとき' do
      it '正常に登録される' do
        expect(page).to have_selector '.alert-success', text: '新規作成のテストを書く'
      end
    end

    context '新規作成画面で名称を入力しなかったとき' do
      let(:task_name) { '' }

      it 'エラーとなる' do
        within '#error_explanation' do
          expect(page).to have_content '名称を入力してください'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end
```

---

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration

require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = "doc"
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

---

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
#Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '>= 3.1.10'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry-rails'

end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.9'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'html2slim'

gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.10', '>= 1.10.5'
gem 'rails_autolink'

gem 'pry-byebug', group: :development
gem 'pry-doc'
```

---

__dir___spec.rb

```
require_relative '../../spec_helper'

describe "Kernel#__dir__" do
  it "returns the real name of the directory containing the currently-executing file" do
    __dir__.should == File.realpath(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  end

  context "when used in eval with a given filename" do
    it "returns File.dirname(filename)" do
      eval("__dir__", nil, "foo.rb").should == "."
      eval("__dir__", nil, "foo/bar.rb").should == "foo"
    end
  end

  context "when used in eval with top level binding" do
    it "returns the real name of the directory containing the currently-executing file" do
      eval("__dir__", binding).should == File.realpath(File.dirname(__FILE__))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`./config/initializers/better_errors.rb`
が未定義のBetterErrorsを参照しているようです。
[BetterErrors](https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/wiki/Link-to-your-editor)に記載のとおり、`if defined?(BetterErrors)`で定義済みかチェックする必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

`better_errors` gemのinitializerファイルをロードしようとして`BetterErrors`クラスが見つからない。という流れのエラーですので、`./config/initializers/better_errors.rb`を削除して実行してみるとどうでしょう。

デフォルトではこのファイルは作成されないようです。書籍のなかで追加されたとかですか？
https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors#set-maximum-variable-size-for-inspector

あとは、`Gemfile`での定義を確認してみるとかでしょうか。

こうなっていると、`development`、`test`の環境で有効になりますが、

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem "better_errors"
end
```

このようにすると、`development`のみで有効にできるので、rspec実行時（test環境）では読み込まれないかと。

```rb
group :development
  gem "better_errors"
end
```